# How to insert a substring to a line in a text file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep, regular-expression

I have a lot of C++ files, that have some lines like this:

`CONST1( var1, var2, var3, var4 );`

`CONST1` is a constant that I know but `var1` to `var4` are variables and can be empty `""`. I would like to automatically insert a substring to all of these lines like this:

`CONST1( var1, var2, var3, NEWSUBSTRING, var4 );`

**Spaces can be present or absent since it is C++.**

I'm ready to use `sed`, `awk`, `grep` or other tools. I tried with sed with regexp but I could not find the way. Do you have a trick to give me?

Comment: Do all of them have 4 variables ? or are there any lines where there's more or less ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution based on comma delimiter - always 4 vars:

```
gv@debian:$ a="CONST1( var1, var2, var3, var4 );";echo $a |awk -F',' '{print $1","$2","$3"," " substring" ","$4}'

CONST1( var1, var2, var3, substring, var4 );
```

With variable:

```
gv@debian:$ a="CONST1( var1, var2, var3, var4 );";b="somestring";echo $a |awk -v x=$b -F',' '{print $1","$2","$3", "x","$4}'

CONST1( var1, var2, var3, somestring, var4 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done with awk:

```
awk -f edit_my_c.awk data_file
```

source for *edit_my_c.awk*:

```
BEGIN {FS=","}

/CONST1\(.*,.*,.*,.*\);/ {
    printf("%s, %s, %s, NEWSUBSTRING, %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4);
    next;
}

{print}
```

And if you would rather pass the CONST1 and NEWSUB fromthe command line:

```
awk -f ./edit_my_c2.awk -v to_match=CONST1 to_insert=NEWSUB data_file
```

source for *edit_my_c2.awk*:

```
BEGIN {
    FS=",";
    my_match=to_match "\\(.*,.*,.*,.*\\);";
}

$0 ~ my_match {
    printf("%s, %s, %s, %s, %s\n", $1, $2, $3, to_insert, $4);
    next;
}

{print}
```

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work fine. The end of the string is truncated.

Comment: End of which string?  Can you example?

Comment: Actually it works. And I'm sorry for not accepting your answer. Both answers work. Now, I'm facing a secondary problem: I found lines with only `CONST1(var1,var2);` and I must convert them to `CONST1(var1,var2, NEWSUBSTRING, "", "");` I tried to add a match but the last parenthesis stay stuck to `var2`... ?